# create a object using static method

Tags: php, oop

I am learning the design pattern. I came up with a example on a site of Factory Design Pattern give below.

```
class Automobile {
  private $bikeMake;
  private $bikeModel;

  public function __construct($make, $model) {
     $this->bikeMake = $make;
     $this->bikeModel = $model;
  }

  public function getMakeAndModel() {
     return $this->bikeMake . ' ' . $this->bikeModel;
  }
}




class AutomobileFactory {
  public static function create($make, $model) {
     return new Automobile($make, $model);
  }
}
$pulsar = AutomobileFactory::create('ktm', 'pulsar');

print_r($pulsar->getMakeAndModel());
```

Here i am unable to understand why a static method has been created in AutomobileFactory Class to return a object. If i can simply do

```
$pulsar= new Automobile('ktm', 'pulsar'); //Its more simple than below code of line

$pulsar=AutomobileFactory::create('ktm', 'pulsar');
```

why static function created for returning a object? if the same can be acheived just using a one line

> $pulsar= new Automobile('ktm', 'pulsar');

Comment: It doesn't seem a good example of a time to use a Factory. You're not building a complex object, nor are you returning anything other that the single object type.

Comment: So, I for one am getting confused. Is your question actually "why is this method static", or is it "what's the point in this factory at all"?

Comment: @Jonnix yes also 'why this static' it will be reallly helpful if you help my why this static function is used for creating the object.

Comment: A factory has one job, and generally doesn't have "state", so instantiating it is often just overhead. You could get rid of the static, instantiate the class and call create as an object method and most people wouldn't bat an eyelid, and the overhead is so small it wouldn't be noticeable. So it partly comes down to personal preference imo.

Answer (score 0):

The Factory pattern is usually useful when the factory can return several concrete implementations of an interface.

Pretty useful when drivers are involved, like db drivers, where the factory could accept the dbname as argument (or better read it from config) and return the proper object for that specific database.

This way, you can use the same instantiation for every supported driver and put the specific db used in config.

Another example would be singletons, but there are some good argument against this pattern.

Answer (score -2):

For implementation of this pattern (Factory method) properly You should define constructor as private, then you can not create object that way:

```html
$pulsar= new Automobile('ktm', 'pulsar');
```

And add to this class public static method which will be responsible for object creation.

Comment: Then you can't create it in the factory either.

Comment: Looks like you are mistaking singleton and factory